# VirtualBox: Failed to load idlinux.c32

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I recently installed VirtualBox on my Windows 10 system having a 8GB RAM and running on a Intel i5 8th Gen processor. I need to use Ubuntu 16.04. So I followed the tutorial I found online and downloaded the ubuntu 16.04.6 iso image and set it as Optical Device in Controller IDE as IDE Secondary Master.

when i start it says: "Failed to load idlinux.c32
                       Boot failed press a key to retry..."
and when i retry i shows the same message.[virtual machine error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OHoi.png)

Comment: Your ISO is probably damaged. Download it again.

Comment: Alright, I will try downloading it again. I may ask for help again

Comment: @harrymc your advise was right, but now i have another problem. when i tried to install Ubuntu, the complete window was not displayed. On the window to select the keyboard, only upto some portion of the back button was visible and I couldn't see the next button. here's the link to the screenshot: https://imgur.com/gallery/q4IBZxa

Comment: By the way, with Linux images there’s usually a checksum file next to the image. You can use these checksums to verify the file was downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error was because of a damaged download file. Downloading again fixed
the problem.

The problem of the installation screen being too large for the default virtual
monitor cannot be fixed before the installation, only worked around.
One of the two solutions below might work for you:

- The black area where it says "Install (as superuser)" might be draggable
- Locating the cursor in the middle of the window and moving it might work, by
  pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key together with the left mouse or touchpad button.